# Determine the smallest positive integer n, which has exactly 144 distinct divisors and there are 10 consecutive integers among these divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We know that after the prime factorization of that number when the powers of those prime factors +1 when multiplied with each other would result in 144.
144 = (a+1)(b+1). . .
We also know that there are 10 consecutive numbers among these divisors so the number must be divisible by 2,3,5,7.

I don't know what to do now , what to do ?

Comment: $110880$ is such a number, but I don't know if it's the least such

Comment: How did u find it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you say is true, but you should apply it.  Factor $144$.  You know that there are at least $4$ distinct prime factors.  There are not many patterns of exponents of primes to choose from, then not many ways to choose the primes so they include $2,3,5,7$.  Make a list of the patterns of exponents, then the smallest numbers that satisfy each pattern.  Sort them and list the divisors of each, starting from the smallest.  I suspect you will not need to search far.  What is the factorization of $LCM(1,2,3\ldots 10)?$  What is the minimum you need to multiply it by to get $144$ distinct factors?  That gives an upper bound to the answer.